# JavaScript: Multiple clearTimeout in array

Tags: javascript, cleartimeout

I have an array with timeout id's. What is the most elegant way to clear all of them at once? Is there a more efficient style than this?

```
waitHandler[1] = setTimeout('doSomethingA()', 2000);
waitHandler[2] = setTimeout('doSomethingB()', 2000);
...

for (var i=1; i < waitHandler.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout[i];
}
```

Comment: Don't write code in strings. `var t = 2000; var ids = [setTimeout(doSomethingA, t), ...];`

Comment: Okay, but what if I need to consign params?

Comment: Then use anonymous functions: `setTimeout(function(){doSomethingA(param)})`

Comment: Ah, is this more performant or just a better coding style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
waitHandler.forEach(clearTimeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean to do is this:

```
for (var i=1; i < waitHandler.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(waitHandler[i]);
}
```

Your old syntax wouldn't work.

---

And this is the only way to do it without plugins.

Comment: Of course. Thanks for your correction and the information that a for loop is needed in pure JS. :-)